# Return png. file from a Jenkins Build

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that executes a python script. I would like to return a png of a figure so that I can see it in the Jenkins Build information. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this to be possible in the following way:

1. Enable (safe) HTML for Jenkins Build descriptions
2. Enter some html that performs a GET request to a path (let's call this X)
3. Set up a mini (Python, Flask?) server that serves this path X, and returns the png image from the correct workspace

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old, but for those who want to know how to get artifacts like images or other files from the pipeline run and just come across this thread, this might help:`archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'some/resources/*.png', fingerprint: true`
This is usually the way to do it in Jenkins. Just paste this into a stage of your Jenkinsfile, adjust the path and the corresponding file/s. I don't think you really need the fingerprint part. There is more useful information here:
https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-archive-artifact-save-file-in-pipeline-ac6d8b569c2c
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/fingerprints/